# is it possible to make a Dynamic application with NSClassFromString()?

Tags: iphone, json, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsxmlparser

I want to use XML or JSON to told my app. I want to make a dynamic application that will change a feature by passing class from XML.

is it possible ? 
if YES, could you please show me how to use NSClassFromString to interface with XML or JSON parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSClassFromString()` only returns a `Class` object. It's not possible to serialize a classes methods and unpack them in this way. You could define your own string format for classes but you can't add completely new methods at runtime (it's against the SDK rules).